# I am trying to turn barge-in to false for audio input and change the end-timeout to a shorter time frame. Documentation reccs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am trying to improve my connect IVR by disabling barge-in and shortening the time between prompts. Per the documentation, I am adding the following as session attributes in my Get Customer Input block:

Destination Key: x-amz-lex:allow-interrupt:mentalillnessIntent:*
Value: false

and

Destination Key: x-amz-lex:audio:end-timeout-ms:mentalillnessIntent:*
Value: 1000

But it's like it isn't recognizing these attributes as the user can still interrupt the prompt spoken in the Get Customer Input Block.

Any advice would be helpful. I will attach a screenshot of how I set it up.

[image: Screenshot of Get Customer Input Block]